# Android: Giving a LinearLayoutManager to a RecyclerView results in Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: android, kotlin

I am simply giving a `RecyclerView` a `LinearLayoutManager` when I am told that this results in a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;`

This is the offending code:

```
var linearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager? = LinearLayoutManager(this)
messages.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
```

Upon further inspection of the `Error` thrown to me, I am told that I am missing `kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics` in my path.

This happens whether I use `kotlin-kapt` or no, which, by the way, I have disabled since `kapt` puts my Android databinding into trouble.

Then I reenabled `kotlin-kapt` and disabled Android databinding, and adjusted my layouts accordingly. Still, no such luck.

And then, I deleted my Gradle cache and restarted Android Studio. The IDE tells me that Kotlin is on 1.2.71 now. Despite this, `kapt` and Android Databinding still do not get along. And I get the same error message.

**UPDATE:** My Kotlin Gradle plugin is 1.2.70, which later turned to 1.2.71. I have also just updated my Android Studio to 3.2, and my Gradle plugin to 4.6 (thus my `com.android.tools.build.gradle` is at 3.2.0) The same thing happened.

I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you try this: remove ? from this statement: var linearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager? = LinearLayoutManager(this)

Comment: No, because messages.layoutManager is of LinearLayoutManager? and is expecting an instance of LinearLayoutManager? as well.

Comment: @MonicaLabbao, do you have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @ConstOrVar yep :)

Comment: `val linearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`

Comment: you can add `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.41'` into your module level build.gradle file

Comment: @RahulKumar same thing is still happening, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually with how `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` gets along with Dagger 2.17: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245. I resolved the problem by:

1. Ignoring my external Gradle script file containing my `ext` and thus managing dependencies traditionally with string literals on my `build.gradle`
2. Downgrading Dagger dependencies and `annotationProcessors` to 2.16 as per advice in the link here.

However, my JVM could have an underlying problem, thus, I am mulling to reinstall my JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try messages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager